# XML via FTP and Memcache slowing my PHP site down all of a sudden....starting today

Tags: php, xml, ftp, memcached

I have the below PHP on my site.

```
$xml = $my_memcache->load('the_xml');
if(empty($xml)){
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
        $host = 'ftp.thirdpartysite.co.uk';
        $file = 'file.xml';
        $xml = file_get_contents("ftp://$username:$password@$host/$file");

        $my_memcache->save( $xml, 'the_xml' , array(), '1800' );

} 
$php_array = $this->parseXml($xml);

$html = $this->gatherHtml($php_array);
return $html;
```

It looks up memcache for the key/value.
It if doesnt find the key it will do an FTP get contents and then save it to memcache for 5 minutes. I only want 1 user having to do this for all users every 5 mins.
Lastly it parses the XML into a php array using my 'parseXml()' function, then turns the PHP array into HTML using my 'gatherHtml()' and returns this.

It has been working for a long time but suddenly it has started making my site really slow. I have not changed the code for a long while. I have it load balanced over 2 servers and the outgoing bandwidth on my internal switch has also shot up. 
I have checked the load and it is low also no DOS attack as average under max threads.

Any ideas please (FTP, memcache, PHP, XML) ?

Comment: You'll have to find out which part is slow exactly - the FTP, or the memcache part.

Comment: check that the ftp isn't the holdup. could be a dns lookup, could be a remote server glitch (e.g, trying to do a reverse dns lookup on your ip), blah blah blah. Anytime you're depending on a remote service, always assume it's the remote service at fault when nothing's changed on your side.

Comment: nothing has changed network or dns side have spoken to admins and file is there on ftp. my code has not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmmm
Well if its nothing on a DNS or Network layer it sounds like it could be something off the third party, in this instance the *XML* file.
If the *XML* has increased in size it's possible it is over the **1MB max size of a Memcache value** now. Source [here](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php). I recommend checking now via an FTP client like Filezilla (or via command line).

If the file IS above 1MB the below could be happening.

**Website slow:**
If this is the case not only will every user not just not find the key in cache, but will also hammer Memcache to try and store it, every time it will fail as the file is too large and will have to wait for Memcache to *timeout* before completing the users page request.

**Bandwidth high:**
I notice you use Memcache, possibly have a node on each web server? If that is true then the data might be trying to write across both Memcache nodes possibly causing spikes in bandwidth on an internal switch.
To confirm this try using tcpdump to check if Memcache is the culprit of the high bandwidth.

```
#tcpdump -vvxXs 1500 -i bond0 'port 11211'
```

Substitute bond0 with whatever you call your NIC.

**Possible solution:**
Try parsing the XML first and THEN once you have what you need write/store that in Memcache. This should ensure that your always keeping under the 1MB value max size for Memcache.

```
$php_array = $my_memcache->load('the_php');
if(empty($php_array)){
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';
        $host = 'ftp.thirdpartysite.co.uk';
        $file = 'file.xml';
        $xml = file_get_contents("ftp://$username:$password@$host/$file");

        $php_array = $this->parseXml($xml);

        $my_memcache->save( $php_array, 'the_php' , array(), '1800' );
} 

$html = $this->gatherHtml($php_array);
return $html;
```

No idea if thats right but hope that helps

Comment: haha the file on ftp area is 1.5mb. copied your solution code and seems to have sorted it. thanks :)

Comment: pleasure. additionally if you are using Memcache >= 1.4.2 then you can configure the Max of Values. See the 1.4.2 release notes. `http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes142`